# H Bridge only working one way

Tags: h-bridge

I have this schematic. My problem is it only turns the motor when I supply the 5v to the right transistor (Q2). I remove the 5v and put it on Q1 and nothing.  I've replace all parts and still does the same thing.  FQP27P06 has an Rdson at -10V, RFP30N06LE has Rdson at 10V.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fATAJJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You're going to have some awful shoot through during the transitions as you start to turn on one FET long before the other turns off.

Comment: I actually do have a diode between the source and drain of each MOSFET, I just simplified it for this question. Of course I've even tried it without them just to be sure and trying to start it by giving q1 the 5v first.  Still no dice.

Comment: Show oscillograms. Consider proper gate drive.

Comment: Please explain @winny.

Comment: Connect your oscilloscope. Probe Vgs for each MOSFET. Post the result.

Comment: There should be either only M1 and M4 conducting or M2 and M3. But there should be never both M1 and M3 or M2 and M4 conducting. M1, M2, M3, M4 should be all isolating to let no current flow through the motor. But how do you want to enable only the non destructive modes with high or low at R3 and R4?

Comment: Are you saying this schematic isn't correct @Uwe?  The input 5v at R3 is from an Arduino I/O.  If I give it 5V it should, from my understanding turn M1 Off and M3 on, the other side should be low so M2 should be on and M4 should be off.  That is my understanding.

Comment: Q1 and Q2 *should* have pull-down resistors to make sure they actually turn 'OFF' when the 5 volts is removed. NEVER leave a logic gate or transistor input floating, as its true state is unknown.

Comment: I will add that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It didn't make a difference.

Comment: When changing the motors direction, break before make should be guaranteed. When going from the state M1 on and M3 off to the state M1 off and M3 on, there should be a short break between both. So turn M1 off, wait some microseconds and then turn M3 on. The same for M2 and M4. It must be avoided that both M1 and M3 are on, even for a very short time. If there 4 control signal to control M1, M2, M3, M4 individually, you could programm short delay periods where both M1 and M3 are off.

Comment: My issue is it doesn't work at all in the other direction even if I start with it first.

Comment: What if changing to the other direction destroys at least one transistor? It will never work in the other direction then.

Comment: @Sparky256 Q1 and Q2 are BJTs, so a floating input will leave them turned off...?

Comment: @immbus. A floating input means an ON or OFF state is not known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an existing h-Bridge circuit that I used in another working project. This one leverages a low-cost H-bridge IC, the Diode International ZXMHC3A01N8. Note the 22K bias resistors used in conjunction with the GPIOs.

[image: H-Bridge]

This circuit is driven by a low-power MCU, similar to your Arduino. The firmware always sets the two GPIO outputs to opposite states to switch the relay in one direction for like 30 ms., then switches them both back to the same state.  Switching the relay to the other direction resets the relay in the opposite direction.

You need to actively apply current flow to BOTH sides of the H-bridge to reverse it.  In your original description, it sounds like you're just removing the 5 volts from one, assuming the other side will switch.  My experience is you want deterministic control on both sides of this h-bridge.

Also, depending upon your current requirements, you may be able to get away with a less expensive, much more compact H-bridge IC solution like mine.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to pull about 12A continuous.